# Why is the title of a 'report' set in smaller font than the chapter headings?

Tags: chapters, titles, document-classes, report, size

I'm writing a document using the report class. I'm noticing the chapter headings look pretty big (and bold), while the main title is much smaller - perhaps 60% the x-height or so.

A(n almost) minimal example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\title{This is my report}
\maketitle
\chapter{The first chapter}
This is some body text.
\end{document}
```

Compile it and see for yourselves.

I know the title page can be customized with various packages (or manually), but how come this is the default?

Comment: Perhaps `\LARGE` was used because front page titles can be very long and it would look awkward on the front page, together with other information like `\@author` and `\@date`, whereas a chapter start page uses `\huge` and there are most likely more pages to follow (otherwise applying `\chapter` there would be pretty useless), such that remaining content is placed on subsequent pages. But in addition, I think that chapter titles should be short anyway, regardless which fontsize is chosen

Comment: Someone decided it to look like that.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes. But why?

Comment: I cannot go back in space and time and look at the thought processes of the person in question, but i guess the thought went along the lines of ... "Yeah, looks about right. I'll go with that."

Comment: @einpoklum: The LaTeX Project members of that time (say about 25 years etc ago) can  justify why they choose such font sizes etc. Ask Frank Mittelbach etc. I am using LaTeX almost 22 years by now and as long as I remember, from my beginning in the late 1990s, the principal look of documents made from standard document classes did not change, so I dare say, that the design decision was about the time when `\documentstyle` was abandoned, i.e. the shift from 2.09 to 2e LaTeX, which is about 1993/1994 -- LaTeX users/project members of that time may correct me, of course

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I was assuming there was some rationale that I was missing and others - not just the original class designers - would be onto.

Comment: @einpoklum: I didn't say there wasn't a rationale... it is apparently not obvious was the rationale was/is. My first comment from yesterday is pure guessing, actually. Nothing profound, nothing confirmed by the responsibles of LaTeX core project

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Fair enough. Let's see if someone knows what the rationale could be then.

Comment: @einpoklum: You could ask David Carlisle in chat. I think he was a member of the project at that time, if I remember correctly